# How do I fix 502 Bad Gateway error with GCP and NGINX

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, airflow

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on creating an Apache Airflow pipeline on a GCP vm instance (https://towardsdatascience.com/10-minutes-to-building-a-machine-learning-pipeline-with-apache-airflow-53cd09268977) but after building and running the docker container, I get this "502 Bad Gateway" error with Nginx 1.14 when try to access the webserver using:

```
http://<VM external ip>/
```

I'm quite new to using GCP and can't figure out how to fix this.

Some online research has suggested editing NGINX configuration files to:

```
keepalive_timeout 650;
keepalive_requests 10000;
```

But this hasn't changed anything.

The GCP instance is a N1-standard-8 with Ubuntu 18.04, and Cloud, HTTPS and HTTP access enabled.

The Nginx sites enabled are :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root Cause**: 
The issue the you experience has nothing to do with keepalives, it is rather simpler - the docker container exits out and isn't running, so when nginx tries to proxy your request into the container, it fails and thus the error. Said failure is due to the incompatibility of airflow with current versions of sqlalchemy.

**Verification**: 
run this command to see the logs of the failed container

```
sudo docker logs `sudo docker ps -a -f "ancestor=greenr-airflow" --format '{{.ID}}'`
```

and you will see that the python inside the container fails to import a package with the following error:

```
No module named 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.clsregistry'
```

**Solution**:

> While I followed the tutorial to the letter, I'd recommend against
> running commands with sudo you may want to deviate from the tutorial a
> wee bit in order not to.

before running

```
sudo docker build -t greenr-airflow:latest .
```

command, edit the Dockerfile file and add the following two lines

```
&& pip install SQLAlchemy==1.3.23 \
&& pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4 \
```

somewhere up in the list of packages that are being installed, I've added it after

```
&& pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \
```

which is line 54 at the time of writing.

If you would like to re-use the same instance, delete and rebuild the images after making changes to the file:

```
sudo docker rmi greenr-airflow
sudo docker build -t greenr-airflow:latest .
```